# Intellij cannot run project

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

When I attempt to run my project in Intellij it fails to run, but it runs fine in NetBeans IDE. Any ideas on why this is?

About my project:

- built with LibGdx
- imported to Intellij via gradle

Log:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: maps/demoMap.tmx
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.Assets.load(Assets.java:46)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.Game.create(Game.java:14)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: maps\demoMap.tmx (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
... 6 more
```

Comment: As the error says ```demoMap.tmx``` is in the wrong place, how are you trying to get this file in your project?

Comment: `tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/demoMap.tmx");` where `tiledMap` is declared ahead of time. This line didn't change and works fine in NetBeans

Comment: where exactly in your project did you put ```demoMap.tmx```?

Comment: core > assets > maps > demoMap.tmx

Comment: do you actually have a `core` folder? Iirc the `assets` folder shouldn't be inside any other folder, it should be at the project root. Something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Dln.png

Comment: My entire project's structure is `EsperantoRPG > core > assets > maps > demoMap.tmx`

Comment: well then I would try moving the whole `assets` folder up one level so it's under `Esperanto RPG` directly.

Comment: That would move it outside the core module and go against the LibGdx file structure

Comment: Ah right, true. Have you set the `Working directory` in your run config as per the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you need to set the `Working directory` as mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA).

> Desktop: Run -> Edit Configurations..., click the plus (+) button and select Application. Set the Name to Desktop. Set the field Use classpath of module to desktop, then click on the button of the Main class field and select the DesktopLauncher class. Set the Working directory to your android/assets/ (or your_project_path/core/assets/) folder! Click Apply and then OK.